# Flutter PageView and AudioPlayers

Tags: flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

i am trying to use pageView to build widget with title, a body, a picture and play audio.

i am having dificulties in playing the next audio when page changes. it plays the first audio but does not move onto the next.

i am very very new to flutter so please explain to me like you would with a child :).

appriciate you'al.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: ListView(
        controller: controller,
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset(widget.entry.image, fit: BoxFit.cover),
          SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          Text(widget.entry.title, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title),
          SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          Text(widget.entry.description,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1),
          //Container(widget.entry.audioStart,)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }


 body: PageView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext buildContext, int index) =>
            PageEntryWidget(entry: pages[index]),
        itemCount: pages.length,
      ),


    final List<PageEntry> pages = [
PageEntry(
        title: 'Cat',
        image: 'images/cat.jpg',
        description: 'sample text',
        audioload: audioCache.load('cat.mp3'),
        audioStart: audioCache.play('cat.mp3'),
      ),
      PageEntry(
        title: 'Dog',
        image: 'images/dog.jpg',
        description: 'sample text',
        audioload: audioCache.load('dog.mp3'),
        audioStart: audioCache.play('dog.mp3'), 
]
```